# Python script opening new VTY line. Don't want this behavior

Tags: python, bash, shell

### Background

I wrote a simple menu system for dynamically creating kickstart scripts that Anaconda will utilize during the deployment of a Linux based application framework. Tools: Python 2.7.14, npyscreen, jinja2

I used Vagrant during development for quick testing. All of my test cases pass a-ok and the menu exits out just fine.

### Issue

When I add the menu into a *.sh file to build a custom ISO, it brings up the menu system just fine. I am able to use it as anticipated. When done entering data, I click "ok" on my main screen and it is supposed to clear the menu, generate data, and proceed with deployment.

When "ok" is clicked, the menu DOES NOT clear the screen. The deployment does continue in the background, however. Changing to the first VTY line (ctrl+alt+F1) shows me the expected output.

### My Question

I am not sure which side to fix this on. It appears that a new VTY line is getting used vs using the first line so that users do not need to press ctrl+alt+F1 to change VTY lines.

### Relevant Code Snippets

```
<*.sh || OMITTED CONFIG>

mkdir -p $ISOLINUXDIR/EXTRAS/kickstart-menu
cp -r ../kickstart-menu/{classes.py,jinja2,kickstart.py,kickstarts,markupsafe,menu.py,npyscreen} $ISOLINUXDIR/EXTRAS/kickstart-menu
cp -r ../kickstart-menu/kickstarts/* $ISOLINUXDIR/ks

</OMITTED CONFIG>
```

And...

```
# Some code omitted

class MainForm(npyscreen.ActionFormMinimal):
    # Home Screen

    def create(self):
        self.name = "MyApp!"
        self.add(MainMenuWidget)

    def on_ok(self):
        self.editing = False
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def exit_application(self):
        self.editing = False
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        KICKSTART_MENU = menuSystem()
        KICKSTART_MENU.run()
        ksCreator(KICKSTART_MENU)

        sys.exit(0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logData(KICKSTART_MENU)
        sys.exit(0)
```